Generic type 'Cheerio<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)
I'm trying to create a function that takes an string (html) and returns a cheerio object that the consuming code can then use cheerio methods on like .find() etc. I cant work out how to correctly type the return so typescript is happy.
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';

export const getInfo = (html : string) : cheerio.Cheerio => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    ....logic e.g.
    const element = $('div#targetId);

    return element; 
}

Then use the returned element in a consuming function like so
const info = getInfo('<div><div id="targetId"><p>thing</p><span>Another thing</span></div></div>);
const text = info.find('span');

I get Generic type 'Cheerio<T>' requires 1 type argument(s). when typing the return of getInfo but cant work out how to use generics to infer the type

What happens if you don't declare a return type?  What does TS infer the return type as?

Thanks for your reply. Removing the return type, I get Property 'find' does not exist on type '(html: string) => any'. when using using the .find() method on the value.

I'm not seeing that.  : cheerio.Cheerio is the return type.  When I do this, TS seems to be able to infer the type well enough? `export const getInfo = (html : string) => {
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const element = $('div#targetId');

return element; 

}
`  https://tsplay.dev/w68LYm

Taking a step back, the design here is a bit odd. Loading the whole HTML just to get one element out of it is going to be slow and is sort of confusing to reason about. The caller should probably load the HTML one time, then optionally use helpers that return data from the once-parsed Cheerio structure, or manipulate the structure if that's what you're doing..
